# Ternary operator no false option

Tags: ternary

I am studying Ternary operators right now and I understand most of it but want to see if this is possible.

normal ternary : (condition) ? (result true): (result false);

question is how to write one with just a true part no false;

(condition) ? (result true):;
or
(condition) ? (result true);
or
Not possible

Answer (score 0):

It's just that would not make sense as expressions must represent a concrete value.

You cannot use if/else clauses as they are no expressions:

`print(if (value > 0) { "yes" } else { "no" });`

But you can use the ternary operator for "inline" evaluation:

`print(value > 0 ? "yes" : "no");`

Assume what happens if the condition is evaluated to false and there is no "result" - how should the compiler know what to print?

Comment: if there is no code there does it throw an error or does it just jump out. Im trying to see if it can be use the same as just the if statement or is this a specific way of doing if else only

Comment: In general, using ternary expression is considered a bad programming style - sometimes, it makes the code easier to read, but usually storing the result in a dedicated variable is much better as it gives you the opportunity to describe what you evaluate using the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript a ternary example looks like this:

```
const value = 1;
const result = value > 0 ? "Bigger" : "Smaller";
console.log(result);
```

> Result: Bigger

If you don't need show "Smaller", you can try this:

```
const value = 1;
const result = value > 0 && "Bigger";
console.log(result);
```

> Result: Bigger

Comment: What language(s) does this work in? Are you sure it does what the OP is asking? (I.e., return `result`)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - this does not look like a ternary operator after all

Comment: The answer is updated, thanks for your comments (Y).